# Undefined MethodError for 'location' for nil:NilClass in rails during Rake Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run this rake task and I am getting the undefined method error for 'location' I am not sure what is causing this error to arise.

my code as follows

```
task :set_location_id => :environment do
  ConfiguredDevice.all.each do | configured_device |
    location = configured_device.user.location
    configured_device.update_columns(location_id: location.id) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Apparently, you have a `configured_device` that doesn't have a `user`. So, when you try to call `configured_device.user.location`, `configured_device.user` returns `nil` and `nil` doesn't respond to `location` (as the error states).

Comment: thank you! how would i go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you have a `configured_device` that doesn't have a `user`. So, when you try to call `configured_device.user.location`, `configured_device.user` returns `nil` and `nil` doesn't respond to `location` (as the error states).

> how would i go about fixing that?

That depends. If it is expected that in some instances a `configured_device` won't have a `user`, then you *could* use ruby's safe operator. Something like:

```
task :set_location_id => :environment do
  ConfiguredDevice.all.each do | configured_device |
    if location = configured_device.user&.location
      configured_device.update_columns(location_id: location.id) 
    end
  end
end
```

Some people don't like use of the safe operator (or the .try() method), so you could also do:

```
task :set_location_id => :environment do
  ConfiguredDevice.all.each do | configured_device |
    if user = configured_device.user
      configured_device.update_columns(location_id: user.location.id) 
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, I suppose it might be possible that a `user` doesn't have a `location`. In which case `user.location.id` will throw a `Undefined MethodError` again. So, you could do:

```
task :set_location_id => :environment do
  ConfiguredDevice.all.each do | configured_device |
    if user = configured_device.user
      if location = user.location
        configured_device.update_columns(location_id: location.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which I think ought to get you where you want to go.

BTW, assuming that `ConfiguredDevice belongs_to :location`, you should be able to do:

```
configured_device.update(location: location)
```

Saves you a few keystrokes.